# how to make an expanded div, that contains half text and half image/photogallery, to work properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to create a "read more" text button, i succed in creating it, but i have some problems when i try to split it in 2 parts -> to be half text and half an image/photogallery ( it is like an article of a newspapper - to the left the text, to the right the image ) http://jsfiddle.net/nN3Uz/6/ . What should i change to this code to work propper my expectaction ?
ps: you can see that the dimensoin of the main div is not working well, ther is no contour to the text before cliking reed more... , what should i change so there will be a border ?
html

```
<p id="title">Math</p>
<div class="expander" id="aspect">
                <div id="paragraf">
                Paragraph 2: Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
                laborum. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est Excepteur sint occaecat 
                cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in c
                ulpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
                </div>
    <div id="image"><img src=""></div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

css

```
#title {
 border:1px solid #800000;
 width:1000px;
 background:#800000;
 color:#fff;
 margin-left:0px;
 font-size: 30px;
 }

#aspect {
width:1000px;
border: 1px solid #800000;
background:#fff;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #494949;
padding-left:10px;
}

#paragraf {
margin-right:10px;
width:500px;
    float:left;
}

#image {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}

#clear {
   clear:both;
}
```

i know there is no problem with the javascript implemented, but there is something wrong with the html or css for the overflowing or whatever is called my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#aspect`

```
#aspect {
    width:1000px;
    border: 1px solid #800000;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #494949;
    padding-left:10px; 
    overflow:auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nN3Uz/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

by default all Div will be displayed as Blocks. One below the other. To display them side by side use **display:inline;** in your style for the corresponding divs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nN3Uz/10/ i tried, but it does not work, it does not show me the image div

Answer (score 0):

To get the border set the min-height of the div

in aspect div use-

min-height: 65px;

and for image div -

min-height: 400px;

and make sure u use the image with height and width lesser than or equal to the size of the image of the div but not greater than that. Or else in HTML use

```
<div id="image"><img src="" height="200" width="400"></div>
```

Hope it helps!!